# disable JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK globally

Tags: php, json

Is it possible to disable JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK in php 5.5 globally ?
I need all my encoded JSON replies to be treated as strings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Disable `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`? Why? As i know, this is just option. If you call `json_encode` without it, it won't cast number (original as string) to integer.

The output of

```
echo json_encode(array('number' => '603'));
echo json_encode(array('number' => '603'), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

is

```
{"number":"603"}
{"number":603}
```

as expected.

If you want to cast all integers from your array to be casted as strings, you should cast them before `json_encode` call.

Comment: PHP 5.5 used to cast all numbers as strings , but in 5.6 and later , things have changed.

Comment: @Hasan things have not changed in PHP 5.6+ `json_encode` still casts all numbers to strings unless you turn on the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option,

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.
However it's a good use case to using objects, like this:

```
class Json 
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $defaultOptions = JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK;


    public function encode($value, $options=0, $depth=512)
    {
        $options = 0 === $options ? $this->defaultOptions : $options;

        return json_encode($value, $options, $depth);
    }
}

$json = new Json();
print ($json->encode([ 'row_id' => '1', 'name' => 'George' ]));
```

So you may to assign to `Json::$defaultOptions` the default options what you want and it'll be  available globally (service).